# export CDK to cloudformation template -python

Tags: aws-cdk

I built a successful python CDK stack and i want to export it as cloudformation template , can someone guide me on that ?

i found the below but it's not in python
https://wp-kyoto.net/en/create-cloudformation-template-using-aws-cdk-typescript/

Answer (score 5):

You just have to run `cdk synth`

In the same directory where the `cdk.json` file is located there should be a folder named `cdk.out`

This contains the synthesized cloudformation templates in json format.